# After Blender symmetrize mesh other side deforms differently

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have made a character and when I select the left side of the bones and symmetrize them they all mirror but when I select some bones to edit their weight everything goes purple. All the bones I am symmetrizing have a .L at the end and I am using blender 2.8 the mesh is also the exact same on each side. I have tried to create new bones, giving them weight and when I symmetrize them they do the same thing. UPDATE: I tried to symmetrize and then re-parent but when I weight painted the bones that caused the problem (I weight painted them identically and no other bones had any weight on them) They would act differently than the originals when posed (the mesh deformed differently).

Comment: Once you've mirrored the bones, have you reparent the mesh? Perhaps share your file so that we can take a look? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/